# Как растянуть блок на весь экран за пределы контейнера?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```
<section class="question_to_you-section section-top">
        <div class="container">
            <?php if( have_rows('question_section') ): ?>
                <?php while( have_rows('question_section') ): the_row(); ?>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-7">
                            <div class="question_to_you_bl">
                                XXXXXXXXX
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-4 offset-lg-1">
                            <div class="question_to_you_br">
                                XXXXXXXXX
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Разметка вот такая и нужно, чтобы на телефоне второй блок был на весь экран, мне его нужно полностью заркасить, а сейчас он только растягивается на весь контейнер, но не за его пределы, но это понятно, но как сделать, чтобы можно было растянуть? Не хочется прятать элемента за контейнером, а потом `display block` ставить.

Comment: div class="conatiner" уберите и div class="row" добавьте класс m-0

Comment: Я не могу убрать container, так как на desktop версии он нужен

Comment: div class="container" задайте стиль max-width: 100%